# Swift DateComponents weekOfMonth returns wrong value

Tags: swift, cocoa, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm working on a calendar view (Cocoa macOS app) that shows the current month. When I try to calculate the week number for a given date, I get different results based on the calendar and locale.

For January 1st, 2021, some calls return `week 0`, others `week 1`:

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let jan2021 = formatter.date(from: "2021-01-01")!

    var deCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    deCalendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_de")
    var usCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    usCalendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_us")
    var deIsoCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    deIsoCalendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_de")
    var usIso = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    usIso.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_us")

    deCalendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: jan2021)    // 0 
    deIsoCalendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: jan2021) // 0
    usCalendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: jan2021)    // 1 ??
    usIso.component(.weekOfMonth, from: jan2021)         // 0
```

January 1st, 2021 is a Friday so I would expect that the "week of month" is `0` (or `1`, depending on if the particular API is zero-based or not).

For February 1st, 2021, which is a Monday, all calls above return `week 1`!

Just for kicks, Jan 31st, 2021: the us/gregorian calendar returns "week 6", all others "week 4".

Bug?, feature?, what am I missing?

For reference:

[image: calendar]

Comment: Why wouldn’t weekOfMonth be 1 for February 1st? And 31st of January is a Sunday which is the first day of the week in US

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on 2 things in a particular calendar:

- `minimumDaysInFirstWeek`
- `firstWeekday`

If you look at calendars you used

```
deCalendar: minimumDaysInFirstWeek=4, firstWeekday=2
deIsoCalendar: minimumDaysInFirstWeek=4, firstWeekday=2
usCalendar: minimumDaysInFirstWeek=1, firstWeekday=1
usIso: minimumDaysInFirstWeek=4, firstWeekday=2
```

So 3 calendars require at least 4 days to consider it a first week, and they start from Monday (day 2 in US locale). Hence 3-day week is not going to be considered a first week.

Calendar 3 has only 1 day requirement for the week, hence even 1-day is a week.

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light onto this. This would explain it. Although I'd say this is somewhat unintuitive. I would have expected the definition of a week to only depend on the first day of the week, which is already different across countries. But then the definition of what is considered a first week is also localized? Who would have thought...